# How can I event_search_max?

Tags: api, max, eventbrite

I'm trying to get all of the events from Eventbrite
but the thing is I couldn't there is a limitation by 100.
Is there any other way going around to get it?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the page parameter to get each page sequentially. Based on the results back, you know how many events there are in total, so you also know how many pages of 100 events there should be.